# How to modify data before inheritance and adopt it after inheritance? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I want is to modify the class config, and then after calling the class I want the modified value to be constant when called in any file I want

```
class config{
    constructor(config){
        this.config = config;
    }
}

class data extends config{
    constructor(){
        super()
        console.log(this.config)
    }
}

new config('123456789')
new data()
```

[image: 2]

Comment: You must be missing a thing or two about inheritance. It has nothing to do with the relation between two **independently allocated** objects.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code by itself doesn't tell us much about what you need help with. Also, it's best to paste the code into a code block, rather a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

When you use extend, you don't need to call config, you can just use data.

```js
class config{
    constructor(config){
        this.config = config;
    }
}

class data extends config{
    constructor(config){
        super(config)
        console.log(this.config)
    }
}

new data('123456789')
```